# SQL: Book-Author Table to Book-Author Table

Tags: sql

I have a table like this.

```
-------------------
book_id | author_id
   1    |     A
   1    |     D
   1    |     C
   2    |     A
   2    |     B
--------------------
```

Is there any way to use SQL to achieve the following?

```
------------------------------
author_id_focal | author_id_co
   A            |       B
   A            |       C
   A            |       D
   B            |       A
   C            |       A
   C            |       D
   D            |       A
   D            |       C
------------------------------
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for showing example data and an example of the expected output. Can you please update the description to better explain “use SQL to achieve the following”; what is it you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, self-join is probably what you want.  Are you sure you want all possible pairs?  I.e. both B/A and A/B, or do you have another way to tell which one is focal?

```
Select distinct a.author_ID as Focal, b.author_id as Co
from MyTable a
left join MyTable b
on a.book_id = b.book_id
and a.author_id <> b.author_id
order by Focal, Co
```